# Downloading file from s3 bucket in React Application

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js

I have a react web app app which, when clicked un a button triggers an AWS lambda (through an AWS AppSync API) that runs an algorithm written in python. After the algorithm runs its output is written into an xlsx (microsoft excel) file and uploaded to s3. The lambda's response is the s3_key.

I want to be able to:

When the algorithm finishes running and the s3_key is returned, click on a button that downloads the xlsx file that was outputted from the algorithm using the s3_key.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!